# How load file .dat in database postgresql

Tags: postgresql

please tell me how to upload a file with .dat extension in postgresql. I need to download about 5,000 files at a time - that is, a whole database

[image]

Comment: Where did you get them from? How were those files created? What exactly do the contain?

Comment: Extensions are not magic.  I can rename any file I want to have the ".dat" extension, but that won't change the contents to a new format.  What is *in* the files?

Comment: Is this the result of a `pg_dump -Fd -d <some_db> `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dbeaver program](https://dbeaver.com/)

This programm export and upload db